# Error in neighbors list on IoTA full node iri-playbook

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, tangle, iri-legacy-api, iota-cli

I have install iri-playbook but when I want to show my neighbors list using this command `nbctl -l`
it shows this error:

```
ERROR: Error response from node: code 500, response: '{"exception":"port out of range:-1","duration":540}'
```

and also the graph and IOTA Peer Manager does not work when I use 
`https://your-ip:5555`  & `https://your-ip:8811`

I follow this tutorial:
[enter link description here](https://iri-playbook.readthedocs.io/en/feat-docker/getting-started-quickly.html)

output:

[image]

how can I solve these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which operating system did you install it on?
Did you configure anything so far? (for example changed any ports or added any neighbors so far?)

By the way this reminds me of something similar I have opened an issue a while back https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/issues/1678

Maybe you've added a neighbor with an invalid port? Please check /etc/default/iri

```
grep ^IRI_NEIGHBORS /etc/default/iri
```

And see if all the neighbors are entered correctly. If not, you can manually edit the file to remove the wrong neighbor and restart iri.